# How to add a space between 2 inputs in print?

Tags: python

So the code I'm doing is this:

```
first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
print("Hi there " + first_name + last_name)
```

What I want to do is make a space so when I run it it shows a space between `first_name` and `last_name`.
When I run the program, it shows:

```
What is your first name? px1se
What is your last name? unknown
Hi there px1seunknown
```

I wanna get a space between the "px1se" and the "unknown".

Comment: I would suggest using an f-string as Richard demonstrated below, but if you are using string concatenation just add a space `print("Hi there " + first_name + " " + last_name)`

Comment: see more on print and spaces here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975168/python-print-statement-adds-spaces-between-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add space between two variables after a print in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969684/how-do-i-add-space-between-two-variables-after-a-print-in-python)

Comment: You don't need string interpolation. Just pass the string parts as separate arguments instead of adding them... `print("Hi there", first_name, last_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your print statement, try the f-string:

```
print(f'Hi there {first_name} {last_name}')
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or, alternatively,

```
print("Hi there " + first_name + " " + last_name)
```

or

```
print("Hi there {} {}".format(first_name, last_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
print("Hi there " + first_name +" "+ last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of sensible approaches offered already, but I thought it might be worth adding the old style formatting to the list.

```
print("Hi there %s %s"%(first_name,last_name))
```